# Use integer as key of associative array does not work on iOS safari

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, safari

I am developing a mobile app with cordova. Tested the app works well with Android but does not work with iOS.

While debugging it, I find when I try to access the associative array iOS always take the associative array as string and returns a char at the index of the key value.

```
var associative = {'5':[{'id': 5},{'id':6}]};
var val = associative['5'];
```

The code above always returns '[' on iOS but returns [{'id': 5},{'id':6}] on Android.

Is this a problem of iOS and safari? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What happens if you use double quotes?

Comment: @NicRaboy It is the same. Looks like I have to use a string not an integer as the key.

Comment: I've tested on iOS and I get [{"id":5},{"id":6}] too

Comment: @jcesarmobile Which version of iOS you are using? I tested on 8.3 and could not make it work. I made it work only by change key to string with characters like 'id5' not '5'.

Comment: I've tested on 8.1.3

Comment: @jcesarmobile I debug the code on mac safari remotely connected to iphone. When I used integer as key the associative array could not be recognized  at all. Strange problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fix working for me is to avoid using integer as key of associative array. After changing the key to 'id5'

```
{'id5':[{'id': 5},{'id':6}]};
```

I can retrieve the value from associative array on both Android and iOS. I believe this is a bug on safari. Maybe it will be fixed on later releases.